# Why won't an integer variable increment by 1 everytime an activity is opened?

Tags: java, android

In my activity below, I have an integer called test. I want this integer to add 1 to itself every time the activity is opened and then get a toast to display its value. I have done this, but every time I open the activity the value is always printed in the toast as 1. Why is this?

```
int test = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hangar);

        final SharedPreferences saving = getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saving.edit();

        test = saving.getInt("testing", 0);

        test++;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello There " + test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        editor.putInt("testing", test);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing [commit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) or [apply](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29):

```
editor.putInt("testing", test);
editor.commit ();
```

Without it, your changes to SharedPreferences are not persisted.